# Error restoring a database from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

When I tried to migrate from TFS2010 to TFS2017, I wanted to restore the databases from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014. The database I tried to restore completed 100% but the following error happens and the database is marked as "Suspect"

> Restore of Database 'test' failed.
>   (Microsoft.sqlserver.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Comment: Can you please post error code.

Comment: Any chance that your source SQL server is not fully updated? Can you try to update it to latest Service Pack and Cumulative Update before creating the backup?

Comment: Have you tried restoring the 2008 backup to another 2008 instance (e.g. a test machine)? More details on your error will help but if it's a vanilla installation and restore, the failure is most likely due to a bad backup or if there's some dependency the database has on external object to startup (check your error log for clues).